# Pyinstaller not working together with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I'm writing a software and was using PyInstaller for packaging/distribution. However, we began to use `matplotlib` and now PyInstaller doesn't work anymore. I wrote a small MCVE so that you can see what's happening.
I'm using Python 3.9.1, PyInstaler's [development version](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip), and Matplotlib 3.5.1 (updated just now) on Linux (although my software has to work on Windows as well).

Here is the MCVE:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(10)
y = [z ** 2 for z in x]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I saved this as `main.py` and ran the following:

```shell
(base) $ pyinstaller main.py
```

This produces an error, with the following relevant part:

```
File "/home/helitonmrf/miniconda3/envs/QSARModelingGUI/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyInstaller/depend/imphook.py", line 364, in _load_hook_module
    raise ImportErrorWhenRunningHook(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
PyInstaller.exceptions.ImportErrorWhenRunningHook: Failed to import module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_IPython required by hook for module /home/helitonmrf/miniconda3/envs/QSARModelingGUI/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks/hook-IPython.py. Please check whether module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_IPython actually exists and whether the hook is compatible with your version of /home/helitonmrf/miniconda3/envs/QSARModelingGUI/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib/hooks/stdhooks/hook-IPython.py: You might want to read more about hooks in the manual and provide a pull-request to improve PyInstaller.
```

The full log is [here](https://pastebin.com/qqBxZfZe).

---

I first tried to update `pyinstaller` and `matplotlib` (and it changed the error), and also tried to add `matplotlib` to `hiddenimports`, but nothing changed.